# Where is the "Hello world" going to be printed after following shadow-cljs documentation to watch the app?

Tags: printing, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, shadow-cljs

I am following shadow-cljs *Quick Start* documentation on a minimal example of a project. Here is [the link](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs#quick-start).

I have this `shadow-cljs.edn` file:

```clj
;; shadow-cljs configuration
{:source-paths
 ["src/dev"
  "src/main"
  "src/test"]

 :dev-http {8080 "public"}
 :dependencies
 []

 :builds
 {:frontend
  {:target :browser
   :modules {:main {:init-fn acme.frontend.app/init}}
   }}}
```

In `/Users/pedro/projects/acme-app/src/main/acme/frontend/app.cljs`, I also have:

```
(ns acme.frontend.app)

(defn init []
  (println "Hello World"))
```

I can build and watch it with the command:

```bash
$ npx shadow-cljs watch frontend


shadow-cljs - config: /Users/pedro/projects/acme-app/shadow-cljs.edn
shadow-cljs - HTTP server available at http://localhost:8080
shadow-cljs - server version: 2.20.2 running at http://localhost:9630
shadow-cljs - nREPL server started on port 61214
shadow-cljs - watching build :frontend
[:frontend] Configuring build.
[:frontend] Compiling ...
[:frontend] Build completed. (127 files, 0 compiled, 0 warnings, 6.97s)
```

Since the `init` function is a "Hellow World" function I was expecting to see it in some place. But, I can't find anywhere "showing" the Hello World to see it worked out.

Where is the "Hello World" supposed to "appear"? Is it supposed **only** to be available in the REPL inside the IDE as a function to be invoked by the programmer?

The "hello world" is *not* printed on the terminal (see above the message retrieved), is not displayed on the UI on `localhost:8080` (that would probably need a tweak in HTML - see pic below), and does not appear on the browser console (that would probably need `js/console.log`).

These are the failed attempts to invoke the functions in the REPL after executing `npx shadow-cljs node-repl`:

```clj
cljs.user=> (acme.frontend.app/init)
------ WARNING - :undeclared-var -----------------------------------------------
 Resource: <eval>:1:2
 Use of undeclared Var acme.frontend.app/init
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cljs.user=> (main.acme.frontend.app/init)
------ WARNING - :undeclared-ns ------------------------------------------------
 Resource: <eval>:1:2
 No such namespace: main.acme.frontend.app, could not locate main/acme/frontend/app.cljs, main/acme/frontend/app.cljc, or JavaScript source providing "main.acme.frontend.app"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the image on `localhost:8080`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have skipped the creation of the `public/index.html`, as mentioned in the Quick Start. The build is using `:target :browser`, so it is meant to be loaded in the Browser. The HTML will do that. When loaded you'll see the `println` in the Browser Console.

For the REPL the code always needs to be loaded before if can be used. So, you need a `(require '[acme.frontend.app :as x])` before running `(x/init)`.